# What happens to stunned civilians?

Tags: xenonauts

Early in the game, stun weapons become available. Their intended use is, of course, capturing aliens alive. But what if I use them to keep civilians from endangering themselves?

Will aliens attempt to execute them? Will they be considered casualties for my mission rating (and make local governments angry enough to lower my funding)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stunning civilians does not give you any penalties. Aliens won't go after stunned civilians either.